# AngularJS watch array of objects with index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have a question about Angular watch within an array of objects.

I have an array $scope.chartSeries with objects as following:

```
[{"location": {values}, "id":"serie-1", "meter":{values}, "name": "seriename", "data":[{1,2,4,5,7,4,6}]}]
```

This is used to draw a linechart with highcharts.

I want to watch this array, and if a value changes I want to know the index and the value that is being changed.

I found several options for watch but none of them seem to fit my situation. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you render and change your array in `ng-repeat`, you can use `ng-change` directive and pass in it a `$index` parameter.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
   <input type="text" ng-model="item.location" ng-change="changeValue($index)"/>
</div>
```

Or you can use `$watch` and work with `newValue`, `oldValue` parameters

```
$scope.$watch('array', function (newValue, oldValue) {
   for(var i = 0; i < newValue.length; i++) {
      if(newValue[i].location != oldValue[i].location)
        var indexOfChangedItem = i;
        //bla-bla-bla
   }
}, true);
```

Comment: Tried implementing this but the `newValue.location` and `oldValue.location' are both undefined...Has it changed since then?

Comment: @MatthewMerryfull, Please, post your question and I will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $watchGroup(watchExpressions, listener).

For e.g.:

```
$scope.chartSeries = [{"location": {values}, "id":"serie-1", "meter":{values}, "name": "seriename", "data":[{1,2,4,5,7,4,6}]}];

$scope.$watchCollection('chartSeries ', randomFunction(var) {
//code
});
```

Or you can use watch for individual values in array to know which ones got changed.